# centrar imagen en un contenedor

Tags: html, css, ionic

Tengo un problema con una imagen a la hora de colocar en la esquina superior izquierda.

Ahora mismo se me centra en el medio del contenedor y se observan los lados blancos del div yo quiero que la imagen ocupe todo el contenedor, pero si pongo whigth 100%; entonces el contenedor se hace enorme yo quiero que ocupe el espacio que ya tengo definido, aunque corte parte de la imagen pero se me deforma todo, el código siguiente está centrada en medio pero no agranda todo, alguien podria guiarme gracias.

Aqui el Html esta la imagen que intento modificar(<ion-img class="product_image").

```
  <div class="main_content_div" *ngIf="dummy?.length==0">    
    <p class="title_p"> Productos cerca de ti </p>
    <ion-row class="items-row">
      <ion-col size="6" class="product_col" *ngFor="let product_item of product_list;let i = index">
        <div class="product_item">
          <ion-img class="product_image" [src]="product_item.image_list[0].file_url" (click)="open_product(product_item)" ></ion-img>

          <div class="product_infodiv">
            <div class="product_rowdiv"  (click)="open_product(product_item)" >
               <p class="product_price"> {{product_item.price +'€' }} </p>
               <ion-icon src="assets/icon/pin.svg" class="pin_icon"></ion-icon>
               <p class="product_city"> {{product_item.address.city }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="product_rowdiv">
              <p class="product_title" >  {{product_item.title }}</p>
              <ion-icon *ngIf="product_item.user_id!=api.userdata.user_id" slot="icon-only" src="assets/icon/chat_btn.svg" class="chat_icon" (click)="open_chat(product_item)"></ion-icon>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>       
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
```

aqui el cogigo css:

```
.main_content_div{
  margin: 10px;
}


.product_item{
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 30%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}



.product_image{
  // border-radius: 10px !important;
  // overflow: hidden;
  height: 30vw;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.bid_image{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  right: 10px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: ¿porqué no usas background image en el contenedor? Te asegurarías que la imagen ocupe todo el contenedor.

Comment: Hola juan gracias , esque la imagen cambia según el producto que sea no es una imagen fija entonces no se como tendria que pasar las variables en css ni si se puede hacer eso.

Comment: Bueno creo que así lo he solucionado: 

.product_image{
  border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 60vw;
  //border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
  object-fit: cover;
}

Comment: Si crees que ya encontraste una respuesta a tu pregunta, escríbela _como respuesta_, no como comentario. Para responder, por favor, lee [answer].

Comment: ha, vale gracias

Answer (score 1):

Bueno creo que así lo he solucionado:

```
.product_image{ 
border-top-left-radius: 5px !important; 
border-top-right-radius: 5px !important; 
overflow: hidden; height: 60vw;  
object-fit: cover; 
}
```